# Dump an Python list to file as code text

Tags: python

Say, I have a python list:

```
arr = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [11,22,33,44]
]
```

I want to dump this object to a file with the code so I can `eval()` it back soon, the content of the file should be :

```
[
  [1,2,3,4],
  [11,22,33,44]
]
```

I don't want to use `pickle` since it is way too slow.

Comment: Use JSON. `eval` is almost always a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cPickle`, and you can do `import cPickle as pickle` so that existing code doesn't have to change. I'm using cPickle frequently myself and 20+MB files load decently fast (layered dictionaries/lists with thousands of entries).

Comment: Yes, cPickle is much faster !

Answer (score 3):

`print repr(arr)`.

Of course, pickle isn't especially slow. And, as zhangyangyu notes, while this works for a list, it won't work for objects whose `repr` cannot be `eval`'d.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `repr`, and then write the result to a file.

> repr(...)
>
> repr(object) -> string
>
> Return the canonical string representation of the object.
>
> **For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.**

But this is not safe, if the file is changed, something terrible may happen.

And what's more, it seems the list in your file is of format. And when this happen how do you convert it back. When you read the contents back, you have to add logic to see if the string represents the list comes to end. If they are in one line, it may be easier.

So, using some existing module is not a bad idea and is the usual way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cPickle`.  It's orders of magnitude faster than `pickle`.